# Compose_Project_Name variable not set warning and network error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

[I am following this Tutorial](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles/blob/master/docs/use_local_hyperledger.md)

Currently I am on Step 2 (there was a few pre-requisite instructions)

Does anyone know why I would be getting the following warning message and error message when trying to install `sudo ./startFabric.sh`
?

> vmadmin@HyperFabricBoilerPlate:~/marbles/fabric-samples/fabcar$
>   sudo ./startFabric.sh
>
> ## don't rewrite paths for Windows Git Bash users export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1
>
> docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down WARNING: The
>   COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank
>   string. Removing network basicnetwork_basic ERROR: network
>   basicnetwork_basic not found

My Project Environment is Ubuntu 16 running on an AzureVM

Answer (score 3):

Please create a file named ".env" in the same directory where your docker-compose file exists. Add the following line in ".env" file:-

> COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=net

After creation of this file, your issue will be resolved. This is related to docker networking, you may find more explanation on following URL:-

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/